# Regex expression with placeholders

Tags: regex-group

I am trying to create a regex to find different placeholders in a file. And the placeholders are like
`%{hi} and {hi}.` 
If I have n placeholders, want to find all of them.
Basic idea is to identify all these placeholders. I am success with individually identifying but not able to combine both to get the desired result.

To find all the matches with %{anything} here are few i tried:
 `%{(.|\\n)\*?} %{.+?} %{\[a-zA-Z1-9\_\]+}`

To find all the matches with {anything} here is what I tried:
`{(\[^}\]+)}**`
Now I am looking for some help to have these two combined and find all the matches with `**%{}** and **{}.**` The order can be anyway and these placeholders can be anywhere in the sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could find both variations using:

```
%?{[^{}]*}
```

**Explanation**

- `%?` Match an optional percentage sigh
- `{[^{}]*}` Match from `{...}` using a negated character class matching any character including newlines

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZbLksx/1)

Another option matching only word characters in between:

```
%?{\w+}
```

Comment: Good answer! @NarendraKumar - To mark this answer as accepted, click the tick mark to the left of the answer. Check [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/676168) to learn how to do it.